# Layout weight and maxWidth

Tags: android

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="56dp"
              android:baselineAligned="false"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minWidth="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/latitude"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minWidth="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/latitude"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:maxWidth="168dp"
        android:minWidth="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img3"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/latitude"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:maxWidth="168dp"
        android:minWidth="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img4"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/latitude"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minWidth="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img5"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/latitude"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want each linear layout child to have a width of 80dp until to 168dp distributing the space. I have no idea how to say using layout weight "distribute the space equally `until 168dp`". I tried to use `maxWidth` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried assigning the parent layout an android:weightSum?

Comment: No, I don't know how to do

Answer (score 0):

You should use [**`android:weightSum`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html).

> Defines the maximum weight sum. If unspecified, the sum is computed by
>   adding the layout_weight of all of the children. This can be used for
>   instance to give a single child 50% of the total available space by
>   giving it a layout_weight of 0.5 and setting the weightSum to 1.0.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:weightSum="10"
      android:baselineAligned="false"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingEnd="12dp"
            android:paddingStart="12dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp">
           ......................           
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingEnd="12dp"
            android:paddingStart="12dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp">
            ..............

        </LinearLayout>
        ...........

    </LinearLayout>
```

**FYI**

AFAIK,  **`android:minWidth`** will not work if you use **`android:layout_height`**

Comment: It doesn't seem exactly what I want. I want to set the max to 168dp.

Comment: @greywolf82 I assume `android:minWidth` not working.

Comment: yep, it seems when you set the weight, min and max have no effect

Comment: @greywolf82 then avoid `android:layout_weight` logic.

Comment: Yep, but how can I say "set a width min 80dp max 168dp and distribute the other"?

Comment: @greywolf82 set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: wrap content doesn't work. Each child is set to min 80dp even if there's more space, so there isn't any space distribution and max has no effect

Comment: @greywolf82 any solutions yet?

Comment: No, I didn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

below layout **distribute equally space** by setting `android:weightSum="5"` to BaseLayout also removed `android:minWidth`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="56dp"
              android:baselineAligned="false"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:weightSum="5">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/latitude"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/latitude"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minWidth="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img3"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/latitude"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minWidth="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img4"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/latitude"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img5"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/latitude"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's not what I want. I want the space distributed equally but until a max value of 168dp. It doesn't work with this solution